# Django REST throwing a 404 error on DetailView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` in my DJango REST application but I get a 404 error when I try to visit the URL.

Here is *urlpattern* in my **urls.py** file which maps to the **views.py** file below

```
re_path(r'^snippets/(?P<username>.+)/(?P<snippet_id>\d+)/$',
                    views.SnippetDetailView.as_view(), name="snippet-detail"),
```

Here is my **views.py** code.

```
class SnippetDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a snippet.
    """
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly]
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'snippet_id'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs['username'])
        return Snippet.objects.filter(owner__username=self.user.username)
```

And this is my **models.py** code

```
class Snippet(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='snippets',
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    highlighted = models.TextField() # to store representation of code
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="", blank=True)
    code = models.TextField()
    linenos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='python',
                                max_length=100)
    style = models.CharField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES, default='friendly',
                             max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["created"]
```

I've been trying to understand what could be wrong with it but am relatively new and I have no idea as to why this is not working. Looked up the documentation and a few examples but I don't see any one of them having multiple named parameters in their **urls.py** file. I would appreciate any help a lot.

Comment: Do you know where the 404 is being thrown? Is it the url matcher, the user lookup or the snippet lookup?

Comment: I think it is the URL matcher. I wrote an almost similar URL for a ```ListCreateView``` with my urlpattern as ```re_path(r'^snippets/(?P<username>.+)/$')``` and it worked when I wrote a similar ```get_queryset``` method but there, I didn't have a ```lookup_url_kwarg```.